# Cocoa launch application window

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nswindowcontroller

I need to implement in Cocoa a initial windows with information and logo of the company such like this:

[image]

My question for you guys is how can avoid showing the window bar:

[image]

I'll really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 3):

What you're referring to is known as a splash screen.  [Here](http://www.knowstack.com/splash-screen-in-cocoa-objective-c/)'s a beginner-friendly tutorial on creating one in objective-c.

Comment: This is great!. Thanks

Comment: Initiate the splash screens with - (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification ?  And use sleep(7)?

Answer (score 2):

Turn off "Title Bar" of the window in Interface Builder (in the window's attribute inspector).

If you are creating this programmatically, the property you are looking for is "styleMask". These are the available masks:

```
enum {
   NSBorderlessWindowMask = 0,
   NSTitledWindowMask = 1 << 0,
   NSClosableWindowMask = 1 << 1,
   NSMiniaturizableWindowMask = 1 << 2,
   NSResizableWindowMask = 1 << 3,
   NSTexturedBackgroundWindowMask = 1 << 8
};
```

Comment: Specifically, you'd use the `NSBorderlessWindowMask` style mask.